# Disabling multiple dates/date range in DateTextbox in dojo

Tags: dojo

I want to use dateTextBox in Dojo for user to select date.And i want to restrict my date selection only for the next 10 days(excluding weekends).
 So if my date starts on monday(30/6/2014) then it should be enable for monday(30/6/2014) to friday(04/07/2014), then  disabl for saturday(05/07/2014)-sunday(06/07/2014) and again enable for monday(07/07/2014) to friday(11/07/2014).

-
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable specific dates by overriding the `rangeCheck` function, for example:

```js
var SUNDAY = 0, SATURDAY = 6, TWO_WEEKS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14;
registry.byId("myDate").set('rangeCheck', function(date, constraints) {
    var isValid = date.getDay() !== SUNDAY && date.getDay() !== SATURDAY; // Weekend check
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var diffms = date.getTime() - today.getTime();
    isValid &= diffms >= 0 && diffms <= TWO_WEEKS; // Two week check
    return isValid;
});
```

I'm using the curent day here to get the next two weeks, but you could add a specific date in your constraints, which are passed to the `rangeCheck` function as well.

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rkC9h/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But suppose i want to disable calender for any holidays. Let's say day after tomorrow is holiday, so how can i disable that particular day/date.

Comment: The function above should return `true` for valid dates and `false` for invalid dates. So, if holidays should be invalid, then you should somehow conditionally check it (for example by providing an array of holidays which you can use to iterate through).